# 404 Error for static files, aspnet core AddSpaStaticFiles roothpath, SPA Template

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services, spa-template

I've created a react project using asp.net core react spa template. Everything seems to be fine, but when I deployed the application in IIS, it is deployed as an application under the default website. When I try to access the site, the index file is coming, but static files are giving 404.

One solution I found is setting PUBLIC_URL to application name in iis and building the application and then deploy. But, **Is there any other alternative solution from asp.net core side? like setting rootPath**

```
// In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/Build";
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is the "application name" you've mentioned? I'm having the same issue :\

Comment: we have the react app deployed like this. 
domainname/{appname} 
appname is just an orbitary name..


But, for us, the Public_Url thing worked as we are going to maintain the same deployment structure in higher environments too.